# While vs Cursor: impact on log file?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am performing some operations on about six million rows of data and I am concerned about the impact on the log file.  For that reason, I am chunking the operations into 10,000 rows at a time.

My question is, will the effects on the log file differ if I use a `while` instead of a `cursor`?

Comment: Try on several smaller data sets and compare log sizes?

Comment: If your operations are insert, update or delete, you might want to keep them *below **5000** rows at a time* . SQL Server will lock on a row-level - up to 5000 rows for a single transaction, at which points it does a **lock escalation** and locks the whole table (which means not even reads are possible anymore). And both cursors and while loop are **RBAR** processing - row-by-agonizing-row - both are horrible for performance and should be avoided if ever possible

Comment: @marc_s Is there a way to keep operations on millions of rows to below 5000 at a time without RBAR processing?

Comment: Where does "5000 rows" come from? I always heard it had to do with what percentage of pages within the table had to be locked.

Comment: As for managing # of rows, the `TOP XX` clause can do this in many cases.

Comment: @PhilipKelley I think what he was referencing was [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx):  "When the Database Engine detects that the statement has acquired at least 5000 row locks in TableB, it attempts to escalate all locks held by the current transaction on TableB."

I'm not knowledgeable enough to know whether or not delete will cause this to occur though.

Comment: Well, how 'bout that--learned something new today! Must be time to go home.

Comment: Though, just quantity or volume of locking really shouldn't impact log file growth.